# UISearchController not showing on iOS8

Tags: ios, uisearchcontroller

I have a UISearchController, whose searchBar is set as my tableView's tableHeaderView:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

It's working great on my device that runs iOS9:
[image]

But when I run it on my device that's running iOS8 there is no search bar.
[image]

From what I've read, the UISearchController is available for iOS8 and later. So I do not understand why its searchBar does not show up on my iOS8 device.

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan I have that already set to true

Answer (score 23, accepted):

UISearchBar is not automatically setting its size add this code:

[searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];

[Apple Sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: This has solved the issue. However, the searcher initially appears over the first cell in the tableView. Edit: I solved this by calling sizeToFit before setting the searchBar as the tableView's headerView. Thanks